# No access to androidx.media (while building mediastyle notification)

Tags: android, androidx

I am trying to add MediaStyle notification buttons to my application. I am a bit stuck. Most guides assume access to the support library. But I think that is not a good idea for my new project and I should use androidx. I hope to have as low as possible future maintenance.

My minSdkVersion is 21 and compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion are 29.

Using these [class mappings](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/class-mappings), I found that 
The support libraries in android.support.mediacompat.R  are now located in androidx.media.R

But, my androidx has no media namespace. (I think this is my main problem).

In my build.gradle I have listed

> implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.1.0'
>
> implementation 'androidx.media:media:1.1.0'

And in gradle.properties I have listed (added by android studio on new project init)

> android.useAndroidX=true
>
> android.enableJetifier=true

I hope you guys have an idea where to look. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Oh wow. Gradle didn't sync. A gradle sync solved it. pff

Comment: Same problem, same solution here, years later